# im making a golf scorecard program in php but want to use javascript for counting the hits

Tags: javascript

now i have programmed in php to hit a button after every hit you make but thats in php so after hit the button the program takes contact with the server.
i would like to know if it is possible to make the hit calculation via javascrit sothat the program does not upgrade to the server an the hits will be visable in the screen and be upgraded everytime via javascript. sothat after ending the hole i can save the result to the server.
i had made the following for test . but still the computer goes to update via the server.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<?
if ($aantalslagen_plus==""){
    $aantalslagen_plus="0";
}
?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
 var a = <? echo $aantalslagen_plus; ?>
      function bereken() {
    a += 1;
    document.getElementById('aantalslagen').value = a;
};
</script>

</head>
<body>  
<form method="post" action="" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "">
<br><br><br>
<table width="422" height="179" border="0">
<tr>
<td>totaal aantal slagen: </td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<?php
     $aantalslagen_plus = htmlentities($_POST['aantalslagen_plus']);
?>
<tr>
<td>totaal aantal slagen php:</td>
<td>
<?   echo "<input type=\"text\" VALUE=\"$aantalslagen_plus\" name=\"aantalslagen_plus\" id=\"aantalslagen\" size=\"10\">"; ?>
<td><? echo $aantalslagen_plus; ?></td>
</tr> 
</table>
<br>
<button onclick="bereken();"> + </button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, that is possible. I assume you are aware that PHP requires a webserver to be executed. If you want a web page that does not require interaction with the server to function (once it was loaded), you cannot use PHP. 
You may want to look into `localstorage` for what you are planning.

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize `aantalslagen` to `0` in JavaScript and don't mess with any `<form>` or POST request or anything like that because you don't need to since it doesn't seem like you're saving the value in some cookie so the value will stay if the user refreshes the page. If you *do* want the value to stay once the user refreshes, I suggest you look into [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage).

```js
//The input element:
var input = document.getElementById("aantalslagen-input");
//The td element:
var td = document.getElementById("aantalslagen-td");
//The button element:
var button = document.getElementById("aantalslagen-button");
//The variable:
var aantalslagen = 0;

//When the button is clicked...
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    //Increment aantalslagen:
    aantalslagen += 1;
    //Update it in the input and td:
    input.value = aantalslagen;
    td.textContent = aantalslagen;
});
```

```html
<br><br><br>
<table width="422" height="179" border="0">
<tr>
<td>totaal aantal slagen: </td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>totaal aantal slagen php:</td>
<td><input type="text" VALUE="0" name="aantalslagen_plus" id="aantalslagen-input" size="10">
<td id="aantalslagen-td">0</td>
</tr> 
</table>
<br>
<button id="aantalslagen-button"> + </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `<button>` is inside of a `<form>` element and the default behaviour is for the form to submit to the server.

Remove the `<form>` element since it no longer seems to serve any purpose.